# Udev rule to allow specific USB devices

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I want to disable all USB devices except 2 types :
- Mass storage devices.
- Touchscreen USB device.

Here's the actual rule I'm using :

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'for host in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*; do echo 0 > $host/authorized_default; done'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb",  RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="EHCI_Host_Controller", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="UHCI_Host_Controller", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="*[Mm][aA][sS][sS]*", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="*[dD][iI][sS][kK]*", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="*[dD][rR][iI][vV][eE]*", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{PRODUCT}=="14e1/6000/a4b4", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
```

So I disallow all the usb devices and I allow hubs & mass storage devices.
I tried to do the same with my USB-connected touch screen but it's not working. I tried all of the following :

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{PRODUCT}=="14e1/6000/a4b4", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ENV{PRODUCT}=="14e1/6000/a4b4", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="6000", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
```

Nothing works...
Here is the result of the udevadm command of my device:

```
root@root:~# udevadm info --query=all /dev/input/by-id/usb-DIALOGUE_INC_PenMount_USB-event-mouse 
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:07:00.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/0003:14E1:6000.0006/input/input12/event6
N: input/event6
S: input/by-id/usb-DIALOGUE_INC_PenMount_USB-event-mouse
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:07:00.0-usb-0:3:1.0-event-mouse
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-DIALOGUE_INC_PenMount_USB-event-mouse /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:07:00.0-usb-0:3:1.0-event-mouse
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event6
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:07:00.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/0003:14E1:6000.0006/input/input12/event6
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
E: ID_MODEL=PenMount_USB
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=PenMount\x20USB
E: ID_MODEL_ID=6000
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:07:00.0-usb-0:3:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_07_00_0-usb-0_3_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=a4b4
E: ID_SERIAL=DIALOGUE_INC_PenMount_USB
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=DIALOGUE_INC
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=DIALOGUE\x20INC
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=14e1
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=70
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=36112
```

When everything is authorized, I have this when plugged:

```
usb 2-3: Device is not authorized for usage
input: DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:07:00.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/0003:14E1:6000.0004/input/input10
hid-generic 0003:14E1:6000.0004: input: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB] on usb-0000:07:00.0-3/input0
usb 2-3: authorized to connect
```